# Extract inner XML elements

Tags: xml, xpath, wso2

**Input** :

```
<a xmlns="http://aaa">
     <b>1</b>
     <b>2</b>
     <c>x</c>
</a>
```

**Expected Output** :

```
<b>1</b>
<b>2</b>
```

**Scenario** :
I need to extract each and every  element of the INPUT inside a WSO2 property mediator

Property Mediator :

```
<log level="custom">
     <property name="symbol" expression="????"/>
</log>
```

Comment: Do you want to select the `b` elements, or the literal text `<b>1</b><b>2</b>`?

Comment: Yes, Exactly. I need to print those